# How does struts2 run custom common method

Tags: struts2

If I have a common static method in a class named `Language.CheckLanguage()`, and I want all action class `execute()` method will call `CheckLanguage()` like this

```
public String execute(){
  Language.CheckLanguage();
  // DO Business logic...
  Return Action.SUCCESS;
}
```

Or any other convenient way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it in a base Action, and extend it from any Action.

Then call `super()` as first row of every `execute()`.

But, if you want it to be executed for every method, not only `execute()`, then you should write an Interceptor.

Comment: Or if you are already using spring you could use AOP, before all calls to execute() then call that method... So your choices are: Inheritance, Interceptor, AOP. I think the order they are written is from highest to lowest coupling. Since you are checking the language parameter to presumably take some action, this does seem to be a good candidate for an Interceptor.